# Show / hide submenu in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have created simple menu:

```
                    <ul class="menu-btn">
                        <a href="#"><li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li>Sit amet, consectetur</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li class="current-page-item">Adipiscing elit</li>
                        </a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <a href="#"><li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li></a>
                                <a href="#"><li>Sit amet, consectetur</li></a>
                                <a href="#"><li>Adipiscing elit</li></a>
                            </ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Quisque sed eros vehicula</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sit amet, consectetur</a></li>                                       
                    </ul>
```

I want to show and hide sub-menu class after hovering on parrent `<li>` element.

Jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
/* navigation sub-menu display */

// Change 'hover' to 'click' if you want to
jQuery('.menu-btn > .sub-menu').parent().hover(function() {
  var submenu = jQuery(this).children('.sub-menu');
  if ( jQuery(submenu).is(':hidden') ) {
   jQuery(submenu).slideDown(200);
   } else {
   jQuery(submenu).slideUp(200);
  }
});

});
```

Now the menu is show / hide but not properly. Because it show/hide `sub-menu` class when I hover on each `<li>` element of the `menu-btn` class.

Comment: Just a heads up: You can't put a link *around* a list-item, you have to put it *inside*.

Comment: why I cannot put a link around a list-item?

Comment: @trenccan you need this http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/200/?

Comment: You don't need javascript for this, just learn how to use :hover an child elements in CSS

Comment: @trenccan It is not valid HTML because the only direct thing allowed in an `<ul>` element is `<li>`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made simple change on your html code and made hove effect with css:

See this codepen.io/anon/pen/PNmyKR